# How to construct a response in Django as specified in finger print reader sdk

Tags: python, django, python-requests

The following is part of a documentation of SDK for a finger print device.
[SDK documentation](http://f02.s.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1PANmFVXXXXaCXVXX.PRXFXXXk.pdf)

Device sends:

```
GET /iclock/cdata?SN=xxxxxx&options=all
```

Thereinto, xxxxxx is the device’s serial number.

server returns (example):

```
GET OPTION FROM: xxxxxx
Stamp=82983982
OpStamp=9238883
ErrorDelay=60
Delay=30
TransTimes=00:00;14:05
TransInterval=1 
TransFlag=1111000000
Realtime=1
Encrypt=0
```

How can i construct such a response in Django?

Comment: can you show your Django code related to your question? btw, I don't think this is related to `python-requests`

Comment: It's not clear what part of this you want Django to do.

Comment: @DanielRoseman constructing an httpresponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal `HttpResponse` (`from django.http import HttpResponse`) is enough. When returned for a GET request, the result in the question is obtained.

```
class SetOptions(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        reply='GET OPTION FROM:'+'23432434454'+'\r\n'
        reply+='Stamp='+''+'\r\n'
        reply+='OpStamp=99999999999\r\n'
        reply+='ErrorDelay=60\r\n'
        reply+='Delay=30\r\n'
        reply+='TransTimes=08:00;09:00;10:00;11:30;13:00;15:00;18:00\r\n'
        reply+='TransInterval=5\r\n'
        reply+='TransFlag=1111000000\r\n'
        reply+='TransFlag=10011111110000\r\n'
        reply+='Realtime=1\r\n'
        reply+='Encrypt=0\r\n'
        return HttpResponse(reply)
```